# Prove a matrix inequality involving norms.

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, inverse

I have the following problem. If  $$\|Ax\| \geq \theta \|x\|$$ for a square matrix A, $\theta$ a positive real number, $x$ a vector and a natural norm $\| \cdot \|$. Prove that $A$ is invertible and $$\|A^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{\theta}$$. 
My attempt, let $x=A^{-1}y$ so $$\|y\| \geq \theta \|A^{-1} y \|$$ and $$\|A^{-1} \| = \sup_{\|y\|=1} \| A^{-1} y \|  1/ \theta \leq \sup_{\|y \|=1} 1/ \theta \|y\|=1/ \theta$$. Is this proof OK?  Also I can't seem to figure out how to prove that $A$ is invertible in the first place, how should I approach this?

Comment: You need to assume that $\theta>0$. Is the matrix square. Can you show that $A$ is injective?

Comment: The matrix is square

Comment: Your attempt is wrong since you write $x=A^{-1}y$ before proving that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: So am I, but am I injective?

Answer (score 0):

Your result is true if $ A \in M(n\times n) $. This way, 
$ |A(x)| \ge  \theta |x| $ implies that $ A $ in injective. By the rank-nullity theorem the dimension of image is $ n $ so the $ A $ is also surjective. Also, $ |A(x)| \ge  \theta |x| $ implies $ \|A\| \ge \theta $. Finally, as $ A\cdot A^- = I $ we have
$$
\|A\|\|A^-\| =1.
$$
Then, $ \|A^{-1}\| \le 1/\theta. $

Comment: Thanks for the answer,can you show why $|Ax| \geq \theta |x|$ implies $A$ being injective?

Comment: Suppose $Ax=Ay$. Then, $0=|Ax-Ay|=|A(x-y)|\ge \theta |x-y|\ge 0$. So we must have $|x-y|=0$. This means $x=y$.